# Fullcalendar 2.9.1 is incompatible with Scheduler 1.2.1

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Have problem with fullcalendar 2.9.1 and Scheduler 1.2.1 or 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1

> v1.2.1 of FullCalendar Scheduler is incompatible with v2.9.1 of the core.

What Scheduler version is compatible with Fullcalendar 2.9.1 version?

I tested ant 1.2.1 Scheduler is compatible with 2.6.1 fullcalendar version, but 2.6.1 don't have one function that I need, and 3.0.0 I can't use that is compatible too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, 1.3.1 version is compatible